# How to test integer(0) condition with if statement in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, int

I have column with integer(0) as value.How to test integer(0) with if condition.

It may be a simple answer but i could not find an effective way to do it.

```
dput(d1):
structure(list(col1 = list(integer(0))), row.names = 37L, class = "data.frame")
```

Tried like below:

```
d1$ col1 <- as.character(d1$col1) ## converted to character first

value= d1$col1
if(value == "integer(0)"){
   do something
}
```

I think above method not correct to check.suggest me how to check that.
Thank you

Comment: `if (length(df$col) > 0)` or `if (nrow(df) > 0)` would work for non-list-columns. What you are suggesting though might be significantly flawed: if `nrow(df)` is always 1, you're fine, but otherwise `if` is not right, consider `ifelse(lengths(df$col) > 1, yes_expr, no_expr)`.

Comment: The `length` of `integer(0)` is `0`. Maybe test for that.

Comment: Does this answer the question? `sapply(d1$col1, identical, integer(0))`. Or to test an individual value `identical(d1$col1[[1]], integer(0))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, It working now. Thank you